# Числа Фибоначчи, рекурсия C++

Tags: c++, рекурсия, числа-фибоначчи

Увидел в одной статье код, считающий сумму первых N чисел в последовательности Фибоначчи, с помощью рекурсии.
Вот эта рекурсивная функция:

```
int sumFib(int n, int p = 1, int c = 0, int s = 0) {
if (n == 0) return s;
return sumFib(n - 1, c, c + p, s + c);
}
```

Как я понимаю это хвостовая рекурсия, верно? Не могли бы Вы, пожалуйста, объяснить, как именно работает эта рекурсия, потому что я что-то не могу до конца понять как она работает и за что отвечают ее переменные "n, c, p, s".
Буду очень благодарен!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, это хвостовая рекурсия. Но в языке C++ не важно хвостовая она или нет. Компилятору безразлично.

Добавим печать, запустим:

```
int sumFib(int n, int p = 1, int c = 0, int s = 0) {
    std::cout << n << ' ' << p << ' ' << c << ' '  << s << '\n';
    if (n == 0) return s;
    return sumFib(n - 1, c, c + p, s + c);
}

int main() {
    sumFib(10);
}
```

> ```
>  n  p  c  s
>
> 10  1  0  0
>  9  0  1  0
>  8  1  1  1
>  7  1  2  2
>  6  2  3  4
>  5  3  5  7
>  4  5  8 12
>  3  8 13 20
>  2 13 21 33
>  1 21 34 54
>  0 34 55 88
> ```

Буквой *N* обозначим аргумент первого вызова. В примере *N = 10*.

В первом столбце номер итерации *n* (уменьшается от *N* до *0*). Во втором - число Фибоначчи *p = F<sub>N-n-1</sub>*. В третьем - следующее число Фибоначчи *c = F<sub>N-n</sub>*. В последнем столбце сумма предыдущих значений третьего столбца: *s = F<sub>0</sub> + F<sub>1</sub> + ... + F<sub>N-n-1</sub>*.

Значение суммы возвращается когда *n = 0*. Сумма в этот момент равна *s = F<sub>0</sub> + F<sub>1</sub> + ... + F<sub>N-1</sub>*. *F<sub>N</sub>* в сумму не включено. Скорее всего это ошибка.

Все утверждения проверяются непосредственно по значениям и доказываются по индукции.

**P.S.** Обратите внимание что значение четвёртого столбца на единицу меньше значения третьего столбца в следующей строке. Или, что то же самое, *s = p + c - 1* в любом вызове `sumFib` ([тот же факт в Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%87%D0%B8#cite_ref-:0_20-0)). Доказывается по индукции. Считать сумму чисел Фибоначчи и сами числа Фибоначчи - почти одно и тоже. Функцию можно упростить, удалив четвёртый аргумент:

```
int sumFib(int n, int p = 1, int c = 0) {
    if (n == 0) return p + c - 1;
    return sumFib(n - 1, c, c + p);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за такое понятное объяснение. Но Вы сказали, что функцию можно упростить удалив третий аргумент, но в таком случае функция не будет работать, ей нужны же данные третьего аргумента для вычисления всех остальных. Или можно как-нибудь иначе написать функцию, чтобы упростить или оптимизировать ее?

Comment: Я описался. Не нужен четвёртый аргумент. Его можно безболезненно везде удалить. Поправил ответ.

Comment: Для вычисления чисел Фибоначчи (и их сумм) есть алгоритм основанный на быстром возведении в степень. Его тоже можно записать в виде хвостовой рекурсии, он тоже будет вычислять пару соседних чисел Фибоначчи. Но в вашем случае выигрыша большого не будет. Функция `sumFib` переполняет `int` начиная с `n = 46`. Большие `n` не имеют смысла.